# iOS GCD use for a UITableView

Tags: ios, multithreading, tableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have a pretty intensive UITableView that needs to be optimized a little. The question is, how to use grand central station to do it effectively. Each cell has a UIView with a couple labels and two images. I have subclassed the TableViewCell and the view's are being reused though it is still a little laggy when the table gets bigger. How would I go about using GCD to optimize the table? OR is there a better way around it? I am not very strong in thread management and looking for some advice.

**Here is the code to my tableview:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
JointCAD *currentCall = [[xmlParser calls] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"texture3.png"]];

TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.callTypeLabel.text = currentCall.currentCallType;
cell.locationLabel.text = currentCall.location;
cell.unitsLabel.text = currentCall.units;
cell.stationLabel.text = [@"Station: " stringByAppendingString:currentCall.station];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = cell.selectionView;

if ([currentCall.callType isEqualToString:@"F"]) {
    cell.imageType = Fire;
}
else {
    cell.imageType = EMS;
}

if ([currentCall.county isEqualToString:@"W"]) {
    cell.imageType1 = Washington;
}
else {
    cell.imageType1 = Clackamas;
}

return cell;
}
```

**Here is the subclassed tableviewcell:**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

    callView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7.5, 7, 305, 65)];
    [callView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [callView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTopLeft];
    [callView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:240.0/255.0 green:240.0/255.0 blue:240.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    callView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    callView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0)  green:(0/255.0)  blue:(0/255.0)  alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    [self.contentView addSubview:callView];

    callTypeLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2, 190, 21)];
    callTypeLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
    callTypeLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    callTypeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    callTypeLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    callTypeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [callView addSubview:callTypeLabel];

    locationLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 17 , 190, 15)];
    locationLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
    locationLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    locationLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    locationLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    locationLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [callView addSubview:locationLabel];

    unitsLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 43, 190, 21)];
    unitsLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
    unitsLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    unitsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    unitsLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    unitsLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    [callView addSubview:unitsLabel];

    stationLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195 , 25, 75, 20)];
    stationLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    stationLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    stationLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    stationLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    stationLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [callView addSubview:stationLabel];

    CGRect countyImageFrame = CGRectMake(275, 10, 18, 18);
    UIImageView *countyImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:countyImageFrame];
    countyImageView.image = countyImage;
    [callView addSubview:countyImageView];

    CGRect callTypeImageFrame = CGRectMake(275, 37, 18, 18);
    UIImageView *callTypeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:callTypeImageFrame];
    callTypeImageView.image = callTypeImage;
    [callView addSubview:callTypeImageView];

    selectionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 7, 200, 65)];
    [selectionView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setImageType:(CallType)newImageType {
imageType = newImageType;

if (imageType == Fire) {
    CGRect callTypeImageFrame = CGRectMake(275, 37, 18, 18);
    UIImageView *callTypeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:callTypeImageFrame];
    callTypeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];
    [callView addSubview:callTypeImageView];
}
else if (imageType == EMS) {
    CGRect callTypeImageFrame = CGRectMake(275, 37, 18, 18);
    UIImageView *callTypeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:callTypeImageFrame];
    callTypeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"];
    [callView addSubview:callTypeImageView];
    }
}

- (void)setImageType1:(County)newImageType1 {
imageType1 = newImageType1;

if (imageType1 == Washington) {
    CGRect callTypeImageFrame = CGRectMake(275, 10, 18, 18);
    UIImageView *countyImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:callTypeImageFrame];
    countyImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"];
    [callView addSubview:countyImageView];
}
else if (imageType1 == Clackamas) {
    CGRect callTypeImageFrame = CGRectMake(275, 10, 18, 18);
    UIImageView *countyImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:callTypeImageFrame];
    countyImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];
    [callView addSubview:countyImageView];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is [xmlParser calls] parsing xml every time?  Nothing else about your code seems like it needs threading.  The images are local, the operations are standard.  XML parsing is costly, so thats why I'm wondering.  If it is, then parse it once and store the array somewhere so you can just call objectAtIndex on that.

Comment: The parser runs everytime a refresh is called, by pulling the table view down. The XML is dynamic and so it is constantly changing, that's why the user has the ability to refresh. I have set up the parser to run in the background using GCD and that helped a little bit. The parser only runs when the refresh method is called and the data is stored in an array. I was just concerned that the views were slowing it down.

Comment: Ok, you still want to make sure that it is only parsing once per refresh.  I didn't get from your response whether or not that function call was causing a parse operation, but if so, it will parse  for as many cells in the table, and I'm guessing you are determining number of cells also with [[xmlParser calls] count].  But yes, doing the parsing on the background is the correct way to do it.  To be safe, you should show some kind of activity cell while parsing is happening (just in case).  call reloadData when the user refreshes, and again when parsing finishes... but on the main thread.

Comment: Call is not a fuction, it's the array that the table data is stored in. And the XML parser runs only once when the pull down is is initiated. Once the parser is done, and the data has been entered into the array, the table reloadData is called.

Comment: +1 for the amusing "Grand Central Station" instead of "Grand Central Dispatch"

Answer (score 3):

This is a little subtle, but the main area your code will hang on is in the setImageType: method.

You're adding a programmatically created Image View into your view hierarchy here:

```
UIImageView *callTypeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:callTypeImageFrame];
callTypeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];
[callView addSubview:callTypeImageView];
```

But you never actually remove the old image view. A better way to do this might be to cache the created image view in a property of the cell, then when you set the image type, send the message -[UIView removeFromSuperview] to the old image view before creating a new one.

As your code stands now, every time a cell is dequeued, a new image view is added to it, so every time the user scrolls up and down the table view, a new image view is created and added to the cell. It won't take long for there to be dozens of image views in each cell. I suspect this is causing many times more drawRect calls into image views than is actually necessary to achieve your purpose.

A better way of doing this would be to have both types of image views as properties that you create in the cell's init method, which are only configured in the setType methods. That way you only create one image view per type, and simply set configure its image in the appropriate setType method. Doing it this way, do bear in mind that removeFromSuperview will release the imageview, so you'll have to declare it as a strong property (assuming you're using ARC).

I appreciate neither of these solutions has anything to do with Grand Central Dispatch, but hopefully that should solve your problem without using a sledgehammer to crack a nut :).